# Make Contract.Assert throw an exception rather than display a Dialog box

Tags: c#, assert, code-contracts

If I'm using the new Code Contracts `Contract.Assert` method, is it possible to make it throw an exception rather than display a dialog box? I want to do this when running unit tests on the build machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to this [post on MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/pex/thread/a2341447-a84b-4f10-8b78-b15d0248160f/) I've found a possible solution.

```
namespace QuickGraph.Tests  
{  
    [TestClass]  
    public class AssemblyContextTest  
    {  
        [AssemblyInitialize]  
        public static void Initialize(TestContext ctx)  
        {  
            // avoid contract violation kill the process  
            Contract.ContractFailed += new EventHandler<ContractFailedEventArgs>(Contract_ContractFailed);  
        }  

        static void Contract_ContractFailed(object sender, System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractFailedEventArgs e)  
        {  
            e.SetHandled();  
            Assert.Fail("{0}: {1} {2}", e.FailureKind, e.Message, e.Condition);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

This appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.contracts.contract?view=net-7.0):

> If your code must throw a particular exception on failure of a precondition, you can use the generic overload of Requires as follows.

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(x != null, "x");
```

This is much more simple than the old accepted solution to this problem.